# How to filter by a member in column

Tags: r, filter, data.table

I have a column which is like below in my data table:

```
Category
_________
{A}
{B}
{C}
{A,B}
{A,C}
{C}
{C,A,B}
{A}
{A,C}
```

from this 
I want to select where the rows where A is a member of category. I am currently using

```
DT[Category=="{A}"]
```

to filter out the rows where category= A but rather than this I would like to have rows which category contains A (like member of in postgres) . Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See `?grepl` for pattern matching. Something like: `DT[grepl('A', Category)]` or  `DT[grepl('A', Category, fixed = TRUE)]`

Comment: Or `DT[Category %like% "A"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Data
df <- read.delim(textConnection('Category
{A}
{B}
{C}
{A,B}
{A,C}
{C}
{C,A,B}
{A}
{A,C}'))


# Slice, keeping only rows in 'Category' containing character 'A'
subset(df, grepl('A', Category))

  Category
1      {A}
4    {A,B}
5    {A,C}
7  {C,A,B}
8      {A}
9    {A,C}
```

Answer (score 0):

grep should come handy here

```
DT[grep('A',DT$Category,ignore.case = FALSE),]
```